# How to take all columns except one column in Data Frame Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

I have DataFrame with for example 24 columns and my question is how can I take all columns except for instance column number 17 ?

`data[:,:]`  using this kind of syntax.

Comment: You can just use the `drop()` function to drop the 17th column, like so: `df.drop('17_column', 1)`

Comment: `df.iloc[:, start_col:end_col]`

Comment: Manakin, but using your code I only take start col for example 1 and end col for example 16, but I want all columns except number 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.r_` with `df.iloc` like below for position based indexing with slicing:

```
pos_of_col= 17
df.iloc[:,np.r_[range(pos_of_col-1),range(pos_of_col,len(df.columns))]]
```

---

Demo , dropping column at position 4 (column 3 since python indexing starts at 0)

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,(5,10))).add_prefix("col_")
print(df,'\n')

pos_of_col= 4
print(df.iloc[:,np.r_[range(pos_of_col-1),range(pos_of_col,len(df.columns))]])



   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9
0     12     15      0      3      3      7      9     19     18      4
1      6     12      1      6      7     14     17      5     13      8
2      9     19     16     19      5     15     15      0     18      3
3     17     19     19     19     14      7      0      1      9      0
4     10      3     11     18      2      0      0      4      5      6 

   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9
0     12     15      0      3      7      9     19     18      4
1      6     12      1      7     14     17      5     13      8
2      9     19     16      5     15     15      0     18      3
3     17     19     19     14      7      0      1      9      0
4     10      3     11      2      0      0      4      5      6
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
data.drop(columns=['a']) # for column name
data.drop(columns=data.columns[17]) # for column index
```

It returns a `dataframe` that you can use.

For more information: [pandas drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: Thanks, its way better than the previous edit which didnt work, I cant delete my answer now but this method is more readable.

Comment: I updated the response. drop([17]) was just deleting rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be:

```
data.loc[:, data.columns != 'col_name']
```

or

```
data.loc[:, ~data.columns.isin(['col_name'])]
```